# Error “tsc.exe exited with code 1" in VS 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms

I am having this error "tsc.exe exited with code 1" for some hours now.

I have the last update for Type Script. I get it when i use the "Bootstrap CSS" package. I tried a lot of suggestions found on the internet, but all of them were in vain.

Comment: could you post the whole error message?

Comment: Please send the exact error message

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47160690/3303195